# Is VeraCrypt encryption of VHDX correct?

Tags: disk-encryption, virtualization

I have created a dynamically expanding vhdx of 500GB to store my backups to - I have decided not to create a 500GB container due to time it would take to create one.

I have encrypted the drive through VeraCrypt with proper algorithms and keyfiles, using NTFS and Quick Format settings; I have mounted the volume and started backup process.

The backup vhdx expands as expected, however I'm not sure if all the data is encrypted.

How could I actually check if the data stored on the drive is encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

To validate your trust in an encryption process, just place a **canary** among your clear data. A good canary is any file with a basic pattern easy to find out with any search tool (I used a file filed with 1MB of U == `0x01010101`).

Boot from another OS, for example an USB key with any Linux version. Mount your encrypted disk, and search your **canary**.

Your **canary** will detect the leak and save you (your data): [Canary use in coal mine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canary_in_a_coal_mine).

Comment: `0x1010101` is likely to occur naturally quite a bit. A more common example of such a magic value would be something like `0xcafebabe`. -1 however because this will not detect if the encryption is _correct_ or not, simply whether or not it is encrypted at all. It could be using A5/2 and your method would still give it a pass.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, VeraCrypt encryption is correct.** Let's assume, however, that it was never audited, and that we are talking about any generic potentially-insecure disk encryption utility. In that case...

There is no easy way to check if a program has correctly encrypted your drive. While it is easy to check if it has not encrypted it *at all*, you will not be able to easily check if it has been encrypted *incorrectly*. I can imagine a dozen failure modes that completely break the encryption but would result in the drive still appearing to be fully encrypted and unreadable without it. For example, a bug that results in the system [accidentally using ECB mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43988/106285), a bug that results in a null cipher key being used each time rather than your own key, or an insecure RNG that creates a predictable master key.

The only way to verify if the encryption was properly done would be to audit the source code. Luckily, [this has already been done](https://ostif.org/the-veracrypt-audit-results/) for VeraCrypt, and the results were, while not perfect, good enough. There were no severe bugs found in the crypto implementation. Another way to verify that at least the encryption is correct is to use a third-party tool to decrypt the volume. If a third-party tool, using a re-implementation of the algorithm, is able to decrypt your volume when the password is supplied, you can verify that the algorithms in use are what has been stated. An incorrect AES implementation that results in VeraCrypt using an algorithm that is not really AES would be quickly noticed when other tools are not able to read the volume, despite having the right key. This does not tell you anything about other issues such as a bad RNG. Those bugs can only be detected through an audit.

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing your backup drive running a live cd with a linux distro. If you can access the drive normally, something's wrong, if not your encryption works.

Comment: Good suggestion - I'll just try opening the drive from VM. However could it be the case that the virtual hard drive headers are encrypted, but the contents are not? I think I will try running some file recovery software against it and see if it can grab any data.

Comment: VeraCrypt sais it encrypts every single file, so it shouldn't be the case "only headers encrypted".